# Can a composite pattern be implemented using list in java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I want a composite pattern to be implemented where the object emp will be added to tl and then tl added to pm. My list should only contain only the pm object, in which the rest of the objects stored sequentially.

But when I iterate and try to print this it displays only the values of pm and not the other two object values.

In this, under one pm object I need two tl objects and under one tl I need three emp objects.

```
List<Entity> ls = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    Entity pm = new Entity();
    Entity tl = new Entity();
    Entity emp = new Entity();
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        emp = new Entity("Associate"  + i, "Salem", 7563214, 3);
        // ls.add(obj);
        for (j = 1; j <= 2; j++) {
            tl = new Entity("TL" + j, "Chennai", 4756921, 2);
            tl.adds(emp);
            // ls.add(obj);

            for (k = 1; k <= 3; k++) {
                pm = new Entity("PM"+ k, "Erode",  5693214, 1);
                pm.adds(tl);
                ls.add(pm);                 
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the last value in each constructor defines the level. I have a button in my JSP from which the level clicked .

```
<div id="company" style="display:none">
```

PM 
TL 
Emp

This list ls is passed to another method in the same class where another list is used to retrieve the values from the list based on the level.

```
List<Entity> subset = new ArrayList<Entity>();
    for (Entity val : a) {


            if (val.getLevel()>=level) {
                subset.add(val);
            }
```

My bean class is

public class Entity {

```
private String name;
private String dept;
private int phNum;
private int level;
private List<Entity> entityList;

public Entity(){}

public Entity(String name,String dept, int phNum,int level) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dept = dept;
    this.phNum = phNum;
    this.level = level;
    entityList = new ArrayList<Entity>();
}
public void adds(Entity e) {
    entityList.add(e);
 }

 public List<Entity> getEntityList(){
   return entityList;
 }
```

Comment: So you problem is in code you haven't shown us? You used three nested loops to create the data structure, do you use three nested loops to print it as well?

Comment: no I used a foreach loop for it.  for (Entity val : a) . Here Entity is my bean class.

Comment: If you use one for-each you will only iterate one level, the top one I guess. If you want to iterate more than one level you need more than one loop, or you need to use recursion which is likely to be a better solution.

Comment: actually my problem is with the list. It adds the pm object and when i try to print it using foreach loop it displays only the pm object values and what i result i expect is i need all that values inside the pm object

Comment: In that case I suggest you print those as well if you need to print them. You know how to use nested loops so it not clear to me what is stopping you from doing this.

Comment: i will edit the question along with more code snippets

Comment: The simplest thing to do is exactly as you have done in the code you have already shown us. You can use a for-each loop inside another for-each or a nest for index loop. Without seeing the code you are having trouble with it's hard to imagine what the problem is.

Comment: It’s a nice design to have each entity be able to print its contained entities — rather than having a “god class” iterate through everything and print it. Also one point in the cmoposite pattern is that if there are three nesting levels now, some other time there may be 2 or 5, and the code ought to work still.

Comment: The posted code is starting to get a bit much. Can you do a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @OleV.V. I have done my best to cover all the code that are related to my problem.

Answer (score 1):

An elegant way to implement what you want will be to implement the toString() method as below. You might want to use append() for other fields as well, instead of joining strings with +.
Here I just copied your code for laziness sake.
You can have <BR> or other formatting tags added to the StringBuilder to nicely format the printed data.

```
public String toString(){
      StringBuilder stringRep = new StringBuilder().append(" Name : " + name + ", dept : " + dept + ", ph num :" + phNum+" ");
      for(Entity subEntity:entityList){
          stringRep.append(subEntity.toString());
      }
      return stringRep.toString();  
}
```

Comment: can yu tell me how to print this in my jsp page?

Comment: Just do what you are doing currently for printing, where you say it is only printing the top level entity. If you edit your Entity class' toString() method, that same code should print the entire thing.